# python -how to handle 'UAE' region phone numbers in phonenumbers library

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
import phonenumbers
from phonenumbers import carrier
from phonenumbers.phonenumberutil import number_type

ph_text = "+97143199099"

if carrier._is_mobile(number_type(phonenumbers.parse(ph_text))):

    print "True"

else:

    print "False"
```

Output: False

please tell me how to handle 'UAE' region here!

Comment: yes I did .....

Comment: This doesn't look like a UAE mobile - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_the_United_Arab_Emirates#Numbering_plan

Comment: thanks for the reply and now i'm validating the region code of the entered string instead of (is mobile number).

Comment: task completed thanks:)